# Does Ghostly Grasp work on all objects?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, incorporeal

The feat Ghostly Grasp (Libris Mortis p. 27) says:

> You can wear, wield, and otherwise use corporeal items as though you were not [incorporeal](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#incorporeality).

Does this include being able to open a door, load a wagon with cargo, pull on a rope, walk on stairs, punch a wall, etc., or only to use items like weapons, armor and gear?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Signs point strongly to "yes"

Fundamentally, this question is "are doors, wagons, cargo, ropes, stairs, walls, etc. 'items'?". If they are, then opening a door would be using it, just like pulling a rope or loading a wagon.

I haven't found a specific rule that says so, but I see strong evidence in the PHB that there's no meaningful distinction between "item" and "object" - including that they're used interchangeably:

From page 5:

> WHAT CHARACTERS CAN DO
>
> A character can try to do anything you can imagine, just as long as it fits the scene the DM describes. Depending on the situation, your character might want to listen at a door, search an area, bargain with a shopkeeper, talk to an ally, jump across a pit, move, use an item, or attack an opponent.

Since characters can clearly open doors, walk up stairs, and punch walls, those all seem to fall under the "use an item" bucket.

It's also clear that "item" isn't restricted to wearable/carriable things (armor, weapons, etc.) from the Halfling description, page 19:

> Halflings are also famous collectors. While more orthodox halflings may collect weapons, books, or jewelry, some collect such objects as the hides of wild beasts—or even the beasts themselves. Wealthy halflings sometimes commission adventurers to retrieve exotic items to complete their collections.

The Appraise skill, page 67, lets you determine the value of items; if a wagon's cargo isn't an item (or a collection of items), how would the players determine its value (or the value of the wagon itself, for that matter)?

> Use this skill to tell an antique from old junk, a sword that’s old and fancy from an elven heirloom, and high-quality jewelry from cheap stuff made to look good.
>
> ...
>
> Appraising a rare or exotic item requires a successful check against DC 15, 20, or higher.

And, from Craft, page 70:

> The basic function of the Craft skill, however, is to allow you to make an item of the appropriate type.

... which explicitly allows you to make mechanical traps, wooden spoons, iron pots, bells, and locks.

The most compelling, though, is the Minor Creation spell, page 253-254, explicitly using both "object" and "item" to refer to the result of the spell:

> You create a nonmagical, unattended object of nonliving, vegetable matter—linen clothes, a hemp rope, a wooden ladder, and so forth. The volume of the item created cannot exceed 1 cubic foot per caster level.

Taken together, it's clear (at least, to this DM) that opening a door, loading a wagon, pulling a rope, walking on stairs, and punching a wall are all interactions with items - doors, wagons, ropes and walls are all items (or portions thereof).